# zend framework application fatal error

Tags: php, zend-framework

i have installed zend framework  on my server zend.twekr.com i have applied all the steps according to zend tutorials but in error_log file it is giving fatal error here is the error

```
  PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class Album\Module in /home/twekr/public_html/zend/module/Album/Module.php on line 7
```

here is the module.php code

```
 <?php 
  namespace Album;

  use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\AutoloaderProviderInterface;
  use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ConfigProviderInterface;

 class Module implements AutoloaderProviderInterface, 
 ConfigProviderInterface
  {
 public function getAutoloaderConfig()
 {
     return array(
         'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
             __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
         ),
         'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
             'namespaces' => array(
                 __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
             ),
         ),
     );
 }

 public function getConfig()
 {
     return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
 }
  }

  namespace Album;

 // Add these import statements:
  use Album\Model\Album;
  use Album\Model\AlbumTable;
  use Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet;
   use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;

  class Module
  {
 // getAutoloaderConfig() and getConfig() methods here

 // Add this method:
 public function getServiceConfig()
 {
     return array(
         'factories' => array(
             'Album\Model\AlbumTable' =>  function($sm) {
                 $tableGateway = $sm->get('AlbumTableGateway');
                 $table = new AlbumTable($tableGateway);
                 return $table;
             },
             'AlbumTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
                 $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                 $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                 $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new 
 Album());
                 return new TableGateway('album', $dbAdapter, null,  
 $resultSetPrototype);
             },
         ),
     );
 }
 }

?>
```

Comment: Seems like your class is declared twice.

Comment: The error message specifies : Album\Module